# Simple Javascript Element width and height Resizing

Tags: javascript

For learning purposes and maybe later on implementing it in React, I made an event system that responds to mouse event to allow element resizing, both in width and height.

For now is just Vanilla JS and a few lines of CSS.

I would appreciate any criticism especially for the event system that I use.

Basically, the black elements allow resizing of the element they surround.

Here is the complete snippet (it is quite short):

```js
// Select the resizers

const right = document.querySelector("#resizable .resizer-right");
const bottom = document.querySelector("#resizable .resizer-bottom");

const events = {
  mousemove: "mousemove",
  mouseup: "mouseup",
  mousedown: "mousedown",
  mouseout: "mouseout"
};

//sides "t" (top),"r" (right),"b" (bottom),"l" (left)

function setUpEvent(resizer, xOrY = "x") {
  const isX = xOrY === "x";

  const parentElement = resizer.parentElement;
  // Define event handlers
  const mouseDownHandler = (e) => {
    // Store initial mouse position and width

    resizer.parentInitialPosition = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
    const rect = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    resizer.parentInitialDimension = {
      w: parseInt(rect.width),
      h: parseInt(rect.height)
    };

    // Attach move and out events
    resizer.addEventListener(events.mousemove, mouseMoveHandler);
    resizer.addEventListener(events.mouseout, mouseMoveHandler);

    // Detach down event to prevent accumulation
    resizer.removeEventListener(events.mousedown, mouseDownHandler);
  };

  const mouseUpHandler = (e) => {
    // Detach move and out events
    resizer.removeEventListener(events.mousemove, mouseMoveHandler);
    resizer.removeEventListener(events.mouseout, mouseMoveHandler);

    // Reattach down event
    resizer.addEventListener(events.mousedown, mouseDownHandler);
  };

  const mouseMoveHandler = (e) => {
    const nextPosition = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
    if (isX) {
      const newWidth =
        resizer.parentInitialDimension.w +
        (nextPosition.x - resizer.parentInitialPosition.x);

      parentElement.style.width = newWidth + "px";
    } else {
      const newHeight =
        resizer.parentInitialDimension.h +
        (nextPosition.y - resizer.parentInitialPosition.y);
      parentElement.style.height = newHeight + "px";
    }
  };

  // Attach initial down event
  resizer.addEventListener(events.mousedown, mouseDownHandler);

  // Attach up event to window to cover the case where mouse button is released outside the resizer
  window.addEventListener(events.mouseup, mouseUpHandler);
}

setUpEvent(right, "x");
setUpEvent(bottom, "y");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Simulates user component */
.component {
  height: 50px;
}

.resizable {
  background: rgba(125, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.resizable .resizer {
  position: absolute;
  /* use the border because it is outside the element  */
  border: 0.5rem solid black;
}

.resizable .resizer-right {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: col-resize;
  right: 0;
}

.resizable .resizer-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: row-resize;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}

.element1 {
  background: rgba(125, 125, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="resizable" class="resizable">

  <div class="component">Resizable Component Content</div>

  <div class="resizer resizer-bottom">
  </div>
  <div class="resizer resizer-right">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="element1">
  Hello
</div>
```

You can also play with it in [CodePen if you prefer](https://codepen.io/mahneh/pen/jOQreZp?editors=1111).